# obtain access token of the System process

Tags: c#, access-token

how to get the access token of the System process from a console application in c# which is running under user account
(actually i need admin access token)

Comment: What are you talking about? What is the "System process"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think you mean "Process Handle" rather than "Access Token".

Answer (score 2):

The "System" process is not a real process.  It is merely a logical place holder for the operating system code that runs in ring 0.  Like drivers.  The abstraction is useful, notably in Taskmgr.exe to give a hint what system resources are consumed by the operating system itself.  Trouble with a runaway driver that burns 100% core could be identified for example.

Actually doing anything with the System process is out of the question.  User mode code runs at ring 3 and has no access at all to ring 0 resources.  No access token exists, it takes a hardware trap to traverse the boundary.  Anything you'd try will produce a security exception.